# Can y of datasets be increasing/decreasing ratio when train regression model?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, dataset

I found many cases in kaggle to predict the quantity or trends. They all set the real quantity as y.

But I have question is that does anyone set the changing ratio as y?

Like:

```
X     y
Day1  0.2
Day2  0.1
Day3  0.15
Day4  -0.1
```

y is the changing ratio compared with previous day.

Why anybody set the real quantity(ex: sales, car numbers...etc) as y rather than changing ratio as y?

I want to know it's based on experience or other reasons

thx

Comment: It depends entirely on your objective, sometimes it may make more sense to use one form rather than the other.

Comment: @user2974951In what case is suitable for predicting ratio? I'm so confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good scenario is predicting the stock market, which can take either a trading or a long-run strategy.

If you want a recurrent trading algorithm, you are more interested in predicting the future price movement, thus you have a ratio (in %) of `price(t0 + gap) / price(t0) - 1`, where `t0` is the time at prediction and the `gap` your desired timespan. You buy the stock if you predict that this ratio will be (largely) positive.

You can also choose for buying "cheap" stocks if you find that their market value is above what you believe to be their "true" value (in currency such as €, $ or £). In this case you are predicting a real value for the stock, and you will buy if `market_price > predicted_true_value`.

Comment: So ratio or quantity as y are all ok. It depens on what objective what we want to predict?

Comment: Exactly. In the end, if you are predicting a ratio (such as 2%) you are inherently predicting a quantity of 0.02, so it all depends on your final goal.

Comment: I thought some linear model can't predict changing ratio like linear regression?

Comment: As stated before, a ratio is just a transformation of your target to a value that it is, by itself, a quantity expressed in percentage. If you have some features and a target (e.g. sales amount), you can both train models to either predict the real value of the sales or the change in relation to previous days.

Comment: But maybe one of both target can't determine the trend?

Comment: Is there anyway to decide how to determine the attribute of y? ration or quantity?

Comment: To decide between ratio or quantity you first have to define your goal for the project. If you want to predict trend, you can either use a ratio (in percentage) or a difference (in value). If you want to predict a real quantity, you use the original value for y. It all comes down to your main goal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89056/discussion-between-urbanofonseca-and-code-worker).

Comment: okay, I'm in the chat box